# How can I manipulate tuple in C functions under PostgreSQL?

Tags: c, postgresql, user-defined-functions

As far as I read from doc, PostgreSQL will pass stored composite type or rows (trigger functions) as a structure of tuple in C. When I am writing my C functions, I would like to be able to manipulate them (create new, read from existing and update existing).

I have searched through the doc but couldn't find a example on how to do that, only few illustrations which may not be enough. Furthermore, when facing a composite type consists of other composite types, how would the structure looks like. As well as variable length types such as text.

If anyone can provide any idea on how to manipulate a tuple structure? Thank you very much!

Comment: there is nothing like the structure of tuple in C. You need to show us the actual datatype.

Comment: This is PostgreSQL terminology. The documentation is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#id-1.8.3.12.10) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#id-1.8.3.12.11).

Comment: Yep I  read the doc. But my problem is more complicated, with more complex type of data and more requirements. The doc only briefly illustrate how to create one tuple, and how to get value from a tuple. But I would also like to know how to change the data of specific entry of a tuple. Of course, the tuple is a structure defined by postgreSQL.

Comment: You cannot change an existing composite value you will have to build a new version of the composite incorporating the changes following the instruction as found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#id-1.8.3.12.11), you can find samples in the postgresql source like in the [build_pgstattuple_type](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/3a4b891964a531aa7d242a48fcd9e41379863ead/contrib/pgstattuple/pgstattuple.c) function

Comment: Hi @Eelke thank you for that, I'm kind of confusing why I cannot change the value of an entry of a tuple since it should be strutted data inside of the memory. I will take time to look into the example you provided though. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @Eelke I can not find any examples inside of the link you provided, could you be more specific of which function or lines they have example of building a tuple or retrieving values from tuple??